# How to change bot username / avatar with Discord.py rewrite?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been searching for how to do this, but it seems the only solutions I could find didn't work.

Comment: could you provide some more details?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`ClientUser.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.ClientUser.edit) on the [`Client.user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.user) object that represents your bot:

```
@bot.command()
async def rename(ctx, name):
    await bot.user.edit(username=name)
```

Comment: How would you change the avatar?

Comment: `await bot.user.edit(avatar=b)` where `b` is some [`bytes`-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object).

Comment: Where does bot come from?

Comment: Also, how do you actually use it to dynamically rename your bot? 